# Error signing a commit on Oracle Linux 6

Tags: git, gnupg

when committing a change, I get the following error:

gpg: problem with the agent: IPC write error

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum -y install pinentry-gtk
```

fixes it

Comment: Thanks for writing up your experience. I wonder if you could add a little more explanation of *why* installing that package avoids the "IPC write error" in question?